# Replacing string literal css class-name in js/react code with a declared constant?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Kinda new to the whole html/js/css/react world... So, let's say I have a react component that generates a `div` that I want to style, so I set

```
<div className={"my-class-name"}>
{// stuff here
}
</div>
```

Then in a .css file:

```
.my-class-name{
    color : blue
}
```

Here "my-class-name" is a string literal, and string literals are bad-coding-101 in every language I've ever used, instead what to do is declare a constant once:

```
const MY_CLASS_NAME = "my-class-name"
```

and refer to the constant everywhere instead of the literal. For lots of reasons (you can change it in one place, you get compile-time not run-time errors, the IDE can know about it, etc.). But it doesn't seem like a css file can look up a javascript constant. Is there a way to do what I want? Am I thinking about this all wrong?

I tried googling, couldn't figure it out, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `<div className={MY_CLASS_NAME}>`?

Comment: In javascript yeah I can do that, but not in the .css as far as i can tell

Comment: Have you actually tried it? What you have there is JSX, which will be processed by React, so it should end up with `<div class="my_class_name">` in the DOM.

Comment: How would the css look? It would work like you say in the jsx but i still have to write `.my-class-name{...}` in .css, so if I later change it to `MY_CLASS_NAME = "changed_it"` in jsx  I would then have to manually go through the .css files and replace the `my-class-name` with `changed-it`.

Comment: It's no different than if you were just writing plain HTML and CSS. If you really don't like to keep the class name into two places, you can use for instance [css-in-js](https://cssinjs.org/) or [styled components](https://styled-components.com) and with the latter forgo classes altogether - they will be generated automatically.

Comment: Yes I agree it's the same as plain HTML/CSS, the same issue would arise. Like I said, kinda new at this. Thanks for the answers, it think css-in-js is what I was looking for.